# Defrosting Waitrose Chilled Chicken Kiev

Tags: food-safety, chicken, defrosting

I had Essential Waitrose Chilled chicken Kiev’s in the freezer for three months and then defrosted them in 8 hours and cooked them. Is it safe to eat them after being defrosted and then cooked like this?
Also can you get food poisoning from eating  chicken that was defrosted too long before cooking?

Comment: Where did you defrost it? In the fridge -> no problem. On the counter -> problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36999/what-are-the-acceptable-methods-to-thaw-food-items) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was actually ok although I defrosted it on a counter but next time I’ll always defrost in the fridge as it is otherwise a risk.